# Speeding up 3D numpy and dataframe lookup

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have a pretty large 3D numpy array (atlasarray - 14M elements with type int64) in which I want to create a duplicate array where every element is a float based on a separate dataframe lookup (organfile).

I'm very much a beginner, so I'm sure that there must be a better (quicker) way to do this. Currently, it takes around 90s, which isn't ages but I'm sure can probably be reduced. Most of this code below is taken from hours of Googling, so surely isn't optimised.

```
import pandas as pd

organfile = pd.read_excel('/media/sf_VMachine_Shared_Path/ValidationData/ICRP110/AF/AF_OrgansSimp.xlsx')

densityarray = atlasarray
densityarray = densityarray.astype(float)

#create an iterable list of elements that can be written over and go for each elements
for idx, x in tqdm(np.ndenumerate(densityarray), total =densityarray.size):
    densityarray[idx] = organfile.loc[x,'Density']
```

All of the elements in the original numpy array are integers which correspond to an organID. I used pandas to read in the key from an excel file and generate a 4-column dataframe, where in this particular case I want to extract the 4th column (which is a float). OrganIDs go up to 142. Apologies for the table format below, I couldn't get it to work so put it in code format instead.

```
|:OrganID:|:OrganName:|:TissueType:|:Density:|
|:-------:|:---------:|:----------:|:-------:|
|:---0---:|:---Air---:|:----53----:|:-0.001-:|
|:---1---:|:-Adrenal-:|:----43----:|:-1.030-:|
```

Any recommendations on ways I can speed this up would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you studied the `dataframe.loc` documentation to see it allows you to specify an array instead of just one index at a time?

Comment: I couldn't see anything, but maybe I'm being blind (or overwhelmed). I have discovered that using .at instead of .loc is quicker (47s or so, so around half the time) but I'm not 100% sure on the difference as yet (although output looks good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the density from the dataframe into a `numpy` array:

```
density = np.array(organfile['Density'])
```

Then run:

```
density[atlasarray]
```

Don't use loops, they are slow. The following example with 14M elements takes less than 1 second to run:

```
density = np.random.random((143))
atlasarray = np.random.randint(0, 142, (1000, 1000, 14))
densityarray = density[atlasarray]
```

Shape of densityarray:

```
print(densityarray.shape)
(1000, 1000, 14)
```

Comment: This works great! Amazing, thank you.

I've tried upvoting you, but apparently I don't have the power quite yet